# Variable from another file

Tags: javascript

I have data.js file with content:

```
var table=[];
table.push('10','11');
```

I want to use it in the other script, which looks like this:

```
var script=document.createElement("script");
script.src="http://xxxx/data.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);

setTimeout(function(){alert(table);},5000);
```

When i paste this to Firebug and run it, at the first time i got

```
function () {
[native code]
}
```

When i run this again i get what i wanted which is:

```
10,11
```

How can i achive this result at the first time i run this script?

Comment: `alert` is not a debugging tool, you should be using the console

Comment: Someone wrote here to set array name to diffrent than 'table'. I don't understand why but this solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug has a function called `table`, presents data in a tabular layout to easily inspect an object. Try going to firebug and doing

```
table("a");
```

And then

```
table({a:1,b:2});
```

That is why you are getting the native function